# How To save(download ) data as excel file from response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, export-to-excel, httpresponse

I was trying to download list of data as excel file.From various posts in stackoverflow I found some help, now I m getting the data in browser as response.Now How to save(download) it in my disk as Excel file?

**Note: my server does not have any MS Office installed.**

```
string attachment = "attachment; filename=city.xls";
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                //string tab = "";
                //Response.WriteFile("hello World");
                foreach (TimesAndMovementsModel item in searchParam)
                {

                    Response.Write("\t" + item.CustomerName + "\t" + item.DurationInMinutes + "\t" + item.StartDate);
                    Response.Write("\n");

                }

                }
                Response.End();
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: 1) This isn't a valid Excel file. Excel may be able to parse it as a CSV but don't count on it. 2) What is the actual  problem? Does your browser not display "Save As" when you hit the URL of your page?

Comment: 1) Do I need to Add values in table format?? like <table>...</table>

2)yes its not displaying "Save As" window.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
public FileResult Download()
{
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("c:\folder\myfile.ext");
    string fileName = "myfile.ext";
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

You can also [read](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/442515/Uploading-and-returning-files-in-ASP-NET-MVC) this article as a reference. Hope it helps!